# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (USING PASSWORD = NO) issue Freeradius server causing aborted connexion

Tags: mysql, mariadb, debian, freeradius

Hi I'm trying to get a mariadb/freeradius/daloradius server up but i keep getting this log from systemctl -xe on my mariadb/mysql service, i came across that after figuring it was the sql connection that was problematic, freeradius shows me the same :

[image]

I'm getting frustrated, i ran across almost every config file, all should be in order but no this keeps happening, the radius server is trying to connect to my root sql user when i pointed to him in his config file that he should use the one i created especially for him and i can't manage to understand why, do mariadb needs the root credentials before even allowing it to connect to it ? I'm clueless please help.

Comment: Made a fresh install of mariadb, authentication through unix socket so no password or such required for freeradius, the only thing is that i get aborted connections to my db (got an error reading communication packets), almost a week trying to resolve this im losing it

Answer (score 0):

This message tell you. that either the credentials in your config is not ok or that root user is not authorized to login.

Best practice is to take your mysql config and try to connect with the mysql command:

```
mysql -h yourconfigurationhost -u yourconfiguration user -p yourconfiguration password yourconfigurationdatabase
```

Be shure doing this with your application user.

Comment: I tried it like this : mysql -h host -u user -p password db and it shows me the help command, running mariadb 10.5.12